# python file writing issue

Tags: python, file

I am working on writing result on a file repeatedly. There are N steps, so I need to write the result for each step on the same file. Then, another module uses the file for the step.

Here is the issue. The file size is 0, so I cannot do the next step.

```
while 1:
    file = open('a.txt','w+')
    run()
    file.write(result)
    file.close()
```

This simple code is the summary of my code.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is 'result' variable that you are writing in a file? Maybe you need a+ mode - to append values - not to rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to assign to `result`?

Also, `w+` [truncates the file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). Did you mean to say `a+`? With your current code, if you kill the infinite loop at any point other than right after the `close()` (and before the next iteration's `open()`), the output file will likely be empty.

Comment: ))))looks pretty  similar to my comment

Answer (score 0):

As @Sang and @NPE pointed out, you most likely forgot to setup result.
But my guess is that you are actually writing to a **local** result variable within 'run' or some other function, and that you forgot to set it global.

In your run function (where wherver you assign result).

```
def run():
    global result
    ...
    result = 42
    ...
```

and then of course, there is the issue of 'a+'.